# Unable to replicate examples of running ironpython in browser with silverlight

Tags: python, silverlight, ironpython, client-side

Basically i am following this tutorial: http://blog.jimmy.schementi.com/2010/03/pycon-2010-python-in-browser.html
According to it, this code should run fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="http://gestalt.ironpython.net/dlr-20100305.js"></script>
  <script type="text/python" src="http://github.com/jschementi/pycon2010/raw/master/repl.py"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/python">
      window.Alert("Hello from Python!")
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And in fact, it does, for example here: http://ironpython.net/browser/examples/pycon2010/start.html

You will see it if you have silverlight installed.

But the problem is that when I try to make the same code run on my PC, I can't do it. I create a text file, copy this code there, save it as test.html, and run with firefox, but nothing happens. Code does not execute, i just get a blank page.
I can't understand the reason why the same code runs here: http://ironpython.net/browser/examples/pycon2010/start.html, but not on my PC, given that it is a client side code, and not the server side.

Comment: do you see anything in the firefox error console? it's in the error console.

Comment: There is nothing in error console. But when I uploaded the same file to my webhosting account, here is what I got in firefox error console: Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http:// sitename .com/silverlighttest.html :: DLR_DownloadResource :: line 15"  data: no]

Comment: @linuxbochs Here is how it looks on free webhosting account: http://silverlighttest.zzl.org/silverlighttest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing to download repl.py; looks like a bug as it's falling back to the DOM downloader when doing cross-domain downloads, but throws. As a work-around copy it to your web-server as well; here's it working: http://www.schementi.com/silverlight/Sunny88.html.

Also, locally you must run under a local web-server as Silverlight isn't able to download any files from the http:// zone while running from the file:// zone.

Comment: Thanks. I will host referred files myself then.